# Counting occurrences of word in a string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, count

I am trying to count how many times a word is present in all of the strings of a Pandas Series
I have a dataframe `df` which follows this logic:

```
word

hi    
hello
bye
goodbye
```

And a `df_2` which looks like this ( scroll to the right to see another column )

```
sentence                                                                            metric_x

hello, what a wonderful day                                                         10
I did not said hello today                                                          15
what comes first, hi or hello                                                       25
the most used word is hi                                                            30
hi or hello, which is more formal                                                   50
he said goodbye, even though he never said hi or hello in the first place           5
```

I am trying to achieve the following in `df`: counting how many times a `word` is present and what is the `metric_x` sum of the values which matches the `word`.

```
word        count       metric_x_sum
        
hi          4           110
hello       5           105
bye         0           0
goodbye     1           5
```

I am using this:

```
df['count'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x: df_2['sentence'].str.count(x).sum())
```

The problem lies in the length of the dataframes, I have `70,000` unique words in `df` and `250,000` unique sentences in `df_2`, the line above is running for 15 minutes and I have no clue for how long it might run.

After letting it run for 15 minutes I got this error:

```
error: multiple repeat at position 2
```

Is there a smarter, faster way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split sentences for words and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), remove trailing values `,` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df2 = df_2.assign(word = df_2['sentence'].str.split()).explode('word')
df2['word'] = df2['word'].str.strip(',')
#print (df2)
```

Then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and aggregate [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for exclude missing values with `sum`:

```
df3 = (df.merge(df2, on='word', how='left')
         .groupby('word')
         .agg(count=('metric_x', 'count'), metric_x_sum=('metric_x','sum')))
# print (df3)
```

Last add to original:

```
df = df.join(df3, on='word')
df['metric_x_sum'] = df['metric_x_sum'].astype(int)
print (df)
      word  count  metric_x_sum
0       hi      4           110
1    hello      5           105
2      bye      0             0
3  goodbye      1             5
```

Comment: hello and thank you. Could you elaborate why your method is way faster than mine?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Hmmm, not sure how get values of `metric_x` to `metric_x_sum`, also faster should be because `merge` is faster here.